# How do I expand an LVM volume (Ubuntu Server)?

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-server, lvm

I have an Ubuntu Server installation, and I only setup 20Gb on the 80Gb HDD using LVM at installation, thinking it would give me more options down the road. I should of just set up the whole partition, or at least a lot more.

I'm not too sure how to approach this issue, the volume is always mounted and the server is used quite a bit (but only for Dev, so it could be shut down for a few).

Here is the output of `$ df -hT` As you can see, I am running out of space...

```
maxxdev@maxxserver:~$ df -hT
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/maxxserver-root
              ext4     18G   14G  2.8G  84% /
none      devtmpfs    745M  248K  745M   1% /dev
none         tmpfs    749M     0  749M   0% /dev/shm
none         tmpfs    749M  1.3M  748M   1% /var/run
none         tmpfs    749M     0  749M   0% /var/lock
none         tmpfs    749M     0  749M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1     ext2    228M   31M  185M  15% /boot
```

and the output of `$ lvdisplay`

```
maxxdev@maxxserver:~$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/maxxserver/root
  VG Name                maxxserver
  LV UUID                enutYN-1zrv-5h0r-DOi0-CnFq-PHon-B4YHlM
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                17.80 GiB
  Current LE             4558
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           251:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/maxxserver/swap_1
  VG Name                maxxserver
  LV UUID                vChwr1-ndWT-hlSo-sxk2-206T-aIE7-Z0eExq
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                836.00 MiB
  Current LE             209
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           251:1
```

If I use the `lvextend -L +50G /dev/maxxserver/root` (or however much space) will I be able to resize the volume while the system is running, plus I need (want) to avoid messing up the partition that is being used now (I guess that goes without saying :)

After resizing, do I still have to 'growfs' for the partition? If so can this happen on a 'live' system, or should I shutdown and do everything with a livecd or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sufficiently new resize2fs and your kernel was compiled with support for on-line resizing you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I will check on those things :) edit: your answer gave me enough info to find some more information. Thats all I needed, some guidance, thanks again!

Comment: I would love to read the rest of this thought right now. Any chance you could continue the post @rhaag71?